# ASP NET Core Web API project, Send Values from form to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I decided to learn ASP.NET Core and I started by build a web page from scratch using the template ASP.NET Core Web API. I created a folder called Pages in my project where I added a razor page called Index.cshtml, in that razor page I have a form that lets a client enter a name and a query into text fields. I then added a new folder called Controllers to this project and added a file called FormController which has a method that is supposed to handle the data entered into the form by the user. I then gave the two input fields the same names as the parameter names in the method that should handle them in the FormController file but when I submit the form, the error **HTTP 400 This page is not working now**.
My form uses the post method to send values to the controller, here is the HTML markup for the form that I am using to capture input from the user.

```
  <form onsubmit="return false;" method="post" asp-route="Form" asp-controller="FormController"  asp-action="GetAction" id="form">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name">Name</label>
       <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" asp-for="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="query">Query</label>
       <textarea class="form-control" name="query" id="query" style="margin-top:20px" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your query" asp-for="Description"></textarea>
    </div> 
</form>
```

The controller that is supposed to be receiving these values from the form looks like this.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ASPLearner.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]",Name = "Form")]
    [ApiController]
    public class FormController : ControllerBase
    {
        //indicate to the method that we only need http post
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult GetAction(string name, string query)
        {
           
            // Redirect to a success page or return a response
            return RedirectToAction("Success");
        }
    }
}
```

I have also added support for MVC and mapped the controllers in my Startup C# code as shown below.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
//configure the services before calling the builder.build
IServiceCollection services = builder.Services;
//add controllers with views
services.AddControllersWithViews(); 
services.AddMvc();  
//add all the razor pages
services.AddRazorPages();
var app = builder.Build();
//alow static styling files to be loaded from wwwroot
app.UseStaticFiles();  
//add https redirection
app.UseHttpsRedirection();  
//add routing for the razor pages
app.UseRouting();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/Index");
app.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.UseAuthorization(); 
app.Run();
```

The form shows up in a modal but when I fill random values and hit send, the page shown in the screenshot is displayed, help me get rid of the error so the values are successfully posted to the controller.

[image: before]
[image]

Comment: Could opening the form in the modal interfere with the controller routing?

Comment: it has no relationship with modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't think you could send the request with `onsubmit="return false;"`
2. `asp-route="Form" asp-controller="FormController"  asp-action="GetAction"` would result confliction

   asp-route="Form

would attach the parttern `/api/[controller]` name of `Form` to the action attribute of form (html element)

```
asp-controller="FormController"  asp-action="GetAction"
```

would attach `/FormController/GetAction` to action attribute

You should remove `asp-controller="FormController"  asp-action="GetAction"`,

3,If your controller is attached with `[ApiController]` attribute,it would bind

data from request body instead of request form,and when failed model validation,it would return 400 directly,you have to add [FromForm] attribute

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#apicontroller-attribute-1) related,try modify as below

```
public IActionResult GetAction([FromForm]string name, [FromForm]string query)
        {

            // Redirect to a success page or return a response
            .....
        }
```

Codes in View:

```
<form  method="post" asp-route="Form" id="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" asp-for="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="query">Query</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="query" id="query" style="margin-top:20px" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your query" asp-for="Description"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Result:

[image]

Tried with modal as you expected:

```
    <div id="dialog" class="modal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form method="post" asp-route="Form" id="form">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" asp-for="Name">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body d-grid gap-3">
                <label for="query">Query</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="query" id="query" style="margin-top:20px" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your query" asp-for="Description"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    
</div>

<button id="opendialog">Open Dialog</button>

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
      
        $("#opendialog").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").modal('show')
        });
    });
</script>
```

Result:
[image]

It doesn't matter,please show the codes related with sending request and press F12,select NetWork and check the request you've sent

[image]

Program.cs:

```
.....
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapFallbackToPage("/Index");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Thanks let me try and update you if I get any results

Comment: Can you try with the form inside a modal because it's still not working on my end.

Comment: I am submitting the form with Javascript, the onsubmit ="return false" is for preventing the default behavior so I validate user input

Comment: I've updated my answer,in fact,it doesn't matter,please show the codes related with sending request and check the request you've sent

Comment: Could it be a Model Validation Error as the Index.cshtml doesn't have a Model class file behind it such as Index.cshtml.cs

Comment: Index.cshtml.cs(Page Model) is for Razor Page ,not for MVC

Comment: Let me try with MVC and see whether I will get something useful then

Comment: In fact,you could try remove [ApiController] and debug,then you could get into the controller and observe httpcontext.request.form/body/header to check the request you received as well

Comment: I think the issue is mainly related with how you sent the request

Comment: Okay let me do that then

Comment: In the second screenshot, the URL reads /api/Form, is API a folder in your project? Where is your Form Controller file?

Comment: No,it just a controller in Controllers folder,[Route("api/[controller]"] would override the default route parttern you registed in Program.cs

Comment: Can I see your Program.cs startup code, maybe am not calling app.MapControllers or something

Comment: But it didn't work with your style, in the gif I saw your asp-route tagged to "api/Form" which also confused me

Comment: i've updated,in fact,I tried followed your settings to reproduce....

Comment: I have defined a Model class with getters and setters for the Name and Query, how do I create a database migration and create a new entry in a table every time user submits a request

Comment: Now it's okay to prevent on default and then use Javascript to validate user input and then submit when everything is okay

Comment: You could follow this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Whats the difference between ASP. NET and ASP.NET Core? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684508/difference-between-asp-net-core-net-core-and-asp-net-core-net-framework  you could check this issue related

Comment: Is it possible to show the errors defined in the model page in red inside a Modal?

Comment: check the html element rendered for validation message and add css codes for your requirement

Comment: I don't think you understood me, when I submit the form then the modal will close, I would like to prevent the modal from closing so that the validation rules I have defined in the Model Page index.cshtml.cs are displayed in the span tags

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76328203/asp-net-core-7-mvc-model-errors-on-modal-popup/76328749#76328749  you could try follow this case

Comment: You also forgot to mention that we both the Route Name for the controller and the "api/controller" needs to be unique for each controller. If you need another controller class foraube deleting records from a table then perhaps it needs to be "api/controller1"  and "Delete" as the route name. Is this correct?